# Custom jsf component to include page with fallback

Tags: jsf, facelets

I'm in trouble with a fairly basic custom component I built (using JSF1.2 and facelets)
It's the same as the regular ui:include, but it renders its own children if the includefile cannot be found (instread of an exception like in ui:include).

Here is the code of the apply() function within my TagHandler:
view plaincopy to clipboardprint?

```
if (path == null || path.length() == 0) {  
       log.debug("Path is empty or 0: src=" + src + ";path=" + path);  
       included = false;  
   } else {  
       VariableMapper orig = ctx.getVariableMapper();  
       ctx.setVariableMapper(new VariableMapperWrapper(orig));  
       try {  
           this.nextHandler.apply(ctx, null);  
           ctx.includeFacelet(parent, path);  
       } catch (java.io.FileNotFoundException ex) {  
           log.debug("Failed to include page: " + ex.getMessage());  
           included = false;  
       } finally {  
           ctx.setVariableMapper(orig);  
       }  
   }  

   if (!included) {  
       // The includepage was not included, so we render the child tags as a fallback  
       this.nextHandler.apply(ctx, parent);  
   }  
   if (path == null || path.length() == 0) {  
       log.debug("Path is empty or 0: src=" + src + ";path=" + path);  
       included = false;  
   } else {  
       VariableMapper orig = ctx.getVariableMapper();  
       ctx.setVariableMapper(new VariableMapperWrapper(orig));  
       try {  
           this.nextHandler.apply(ctx, null);  
           ctx.includeFacelet(parent, path);  
       } catch (java.io.FileNotFoundException ex) {  
           log.debug("Failed to include page: " + ex.getMessage());  
           included = false;  
       } finally {  
           ctx.setVariableMapper(orig);  
       }  
   }  

   if (!included) {  
       // The includepage was not included, so we render the child tags as a fallback  
       this.nextHandler.apply(ctx, parent);  
   }
```

Problem is though, that the code fails on the "this.nextHandler.apply(ctx, null), saying "Parent UIComponent is null.
It doesn't give me an error there when I make sure that the tag does not have any child tags...

Is there any facelets expert around here who knows what I'm doing wrong?
Thanks a lot in advance!